# nav_menu with blue icon items displaying white

Tags: android, xml

In **nav_menu.xml** I have a list of icons to show in NavigationView.
The problem is that the icons are linked with the drawable folder and those icons are BLUE, but when I debug the app in the navigation show me white.

**base.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/lista"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/gris"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/azulOscuro"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"

    app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"/>
```

**nav_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_blue"
        android:title="@string/title"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/configuration_section"
        android:title="Example">

        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/example2"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_maps_blue"
                android:title="@string/title"/>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/example3"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_maps_blue"
                android:title="@string/title"/>

                                 ...
                                 ...
</menu>
```

May be you can help me. Thanks

Comment: what is `color/gris` value??

Comment: @FahadRehman gris = grey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ur colour drawble images in item tags and in your code 
try this

```
// add normal color to navigationView
navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

also you can do it using xml 
try this

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    ...
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/black" 
    ... />
```

or

```
 app:itemIconTint="@null"
```

Comment: And how can I change also the color of each group in the navigationview?

Comment: no you dont need to do anything regarding the groups ,do it to the main view and group items will be affected ,by adding color  as null it will display the normal color of drawble images or you can simply say black and all will be black

Comment: go and put app:itemIconTint in the navigation view not in each item